# returning json object in a modal to a grid and editing it in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I constructed a ui grid which has a column for editing, the grid information is populated by a json. Upon clicking the edit column a modal is opened. I want the user to be able to edit the row it clicked. So far I was able to return the entire json object to the modal, but I'm having trouble understanding how to turn that object into just the row I want to edit. I have a variable named ClickedRow which returns the $$hashkey id but I'm not sure how to access it. I tried a forEach utility but it's not working. I am new to angularjs can anyone help me

This is my controller:

```
    import {safeApply} from 'ems';
    import modalTemplate from './modal/modal.html';
    import controller from './modal/modal.controller.js';

    class AssetsController {
      /* @ngInject */
      constructor(AssetsService, $uibModal, $state) {
        this.label = 'Assets Controller !!';
        this.assetsService = AssetsService;
        this.assetModal= $uibModal;
        this.$state = $state;
        var assetsData;
        var clickedRow;
        this.assetsService.resolvePromise().then((response) => {
          this.gridOptions.data = response;
          assetsData = this.gridOptions.data;
          //console.log(response);
          safeApply();
        });
        this.modalOptions ={
          template: modalTemplate,
          controller: controller,
          size: 'large',
          backdrop: false,
          resolve: {
            assetData: function(){
              console.log('number 2'+clickedRow);
              return [clickedRow, assetsData];

            }
          }
        };
        this.myAppScopeProvider ={
          modal: this.assetModal,
          modalOptions: this.modalOptions,
          open:function(row){
            console.log('number 1'+row);
            clickedRow = row;
            this.modal.open(this.modalOptions)
          }
          };
        this.initialize();

      }


      initialize() {

        this.gridOptions = {
          paginationPageSizes: [15, 30, 45],
          paginationPageSize: 9,
          rowHeight: 50,
          enableRowSelection: true,
          enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
          multiSelect: false,
          enableColumnResizing: true,
          enableSelectAll: false,
          noUnselect: true,
          columnDefs: [
            {
              field: 'Thumbnail',
              displayName: '',
              width: 100,
              cellTemplate: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span>'
            },
            {
              field: 'File Name',
              displayName: 'File Name',
              cellClass:'blue',
              width: 100
            },
            {
              field: 'Description_',
              displayName: 'Description',
              minWidth: 150
            },
            {
              field: 'Edit_',
              displayName: 'Edit',
              cellTemplate: '<button class="btn btn-link pull-right" ng-click="grid.appScope.open(row)">Edit</button>',
              cellClass:'blue',
              width: 100
            },
            { field: 'Uploaded_Date', displayName: 'Upload Date'},
            { field: 'Uploaded_By'},
            { field: 'File_Size' },
            { field: 'File_Source'},
            { field: 'In_Use'},
            {
              field: 'Lock_Status',
              displayName: '',
              cellClass:'black',
              cellTemplate: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true">'
            }
          ],
          onRegisterApi:function (gridApi) {
            this.gridApi = gridApi;
          },
          appScopeProvider: this.myAppScopeProvider,
          rowTemplate:''
        };

      }
    }

    export default AssetsController;  


class ModalController {
  /* @ngInject */
  constructor($scope, $uibModalInstance, assetData) {
    this.label = 'Modal Controller !!';
    this.scope = $scope;
    this.scope.assetData = assetData;
  }
  initialize() {
   /* this.modalService.resolvePromise().then((response) => {
      this.data = response.data;
    });*/
  }
}

export default ModalController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `row.entity` as parameter to your `open` method:

```
<button class="btn btn-link pull-right" ng-click="grid.appScope.open(row.entity)">Edit</button>
```

You'll need to declare your `resolve` object in your `open` method so you can pass `entity` directly:

```
open: function (entity) {
    this.modalOptions.resolve = {
        entity: entity
    }
    this.modal.open(this.modalOptions)
}
```

Inject `entity` into your modal controller and you're good to go

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Agvcc6CZFBvQQLRpQeRk?p=preview

Comment: when I try and declare my resolve in my open function I get a provider error?

Comment: Works for me, added an example to my answer so you can verify